# "Я стою на склоне первого перевала в сторону Альп"?

Tags: выбор-слов, управление

Это и всё. Я про перевалы мало-мало понимаю.

Может ли перевал - как жгучий взгляд! - быть в чью-либо сторону?

Comment: Перевала на пути к Альпам? Сейчас он "стоит в сторону".

Comment: Сашко, с добрым утром! Я не про как поправить, а - можно ли не править? Криминал-то есть-нет?

Comment: Я не воспринимаю "перевал в сторону": при такой логике автора, находясь по другую сторону перевала, он назвал бы его по-другому. Значит, дело в расположени автора, а не в свойствах перевала. Надо говорить о направлении движения или взгляда (напр. глядя или устремив его в сторону Альп).

Answer (score 1):

*Я стою на склоне первого перевала **в сторону Альп**.*

Я думаю так.

Горный альпийский массив имеет ряд перевалов (удобных переходов через него). Вероятно, автор стоит на  склоне, с которого начинается перевал.

А в сторону Альп — это указание на то, что это перевал именно **через Альпы.**